# Tortoise SVN merging repository with working copy

Tags: excel, svn, merge

I've tried searching for answers to my problem but every thread starts talking about branches and trunks and I have no idea what they're talking about.

I'm in a team of 2. We've started working on a single excel spreadsheet. I use SVN update before making my changes, however while I'm making changes, my team-mate also makes changes and commits them before I do.

I was first told that I simply have to update again before I commit and it should merge my team-mate's changes with mine. However when I update the .xlsx file, nothing seems to happen. I open up my local copy again and it isn't showing my team-mates changes. I've tried using the merge option and clicked random things in numerous attempts but nothing works. Nothing I've tried will add my team-mates changes to my working copy. Every time I compare my working copy with the repository, the changes from both of us are all highlighted, but nothing I do seems to merge them together.

The cells we modify in the spreadsheet are different ones, so we don't both make direct changes to the same cell. It should be a simple merge.

This is driving me up the wall, it keeps saying "merge successful" or "update successful" but it isn't doing anything.

Comment: Is the spreadsheet in source control?

Comment: yes, it is in source control

Comment: You should learn about version control. For example, read SVNBook http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html

Comment: @bahrep - it's MSOffice, no luck with versioning anyway

Answer (score 0):

.xlsx files are not text-files (they are really zip-archives), don't expect merging of such files from Subversion in **any** case

You can't have *easy* teamwork with Office's documents

Comment: There are some SVN-based plug-ins for Office as far I know. E.g. http://magnetsvn.com/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, xlsx files are binary rather than textual so SVN cannot merge them very well. So two of you working on one such file at the same time will not work well even if nothing goes wrong.

As for why you never saw the changes, probably you still had the file with *your* changes open in Excel when you did your update, and Excel never prompted to load the new changes.

To correct the immediate situation you can move your version of the file elsewhere, svn update to get the repository version back, and manually compare and resolve the differences.

In the future, since SVN is not suited well for merging this type of file, set the `svn:needs-lock` property on this file, and always be sure to `svn lock` it before editing to keep your coworkers from making changes at the same time.

If you *need* simultaneous editing capabilities, look into what cloud services Microsoft offers, or switch to Google Docs or similar.